# Can I convert Jfrog OSS account to Enterprise Edition account later?

Tags: account, bintray

I'm planning to create an open source project.
There are two types of JFrog account.
1. OSS (Open Source Project)
2. Enterprise Edition

For now, I don't need Enterprise Edition.
But later if I need Enterprise Edition account for my company, is it possible to convert account type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, in my opinion, is to open an account and creating an organization on your company name.
In the future you can make that organization Enterprise.
You can also add users to your organization.

To wrap it up:

1. Signup as OSS user
2. Create OSS organization on your Company name
3. Change to Enterprise organization when needed